Contractive Projections: Formation of Proper Subspaces and Implications in Complemented Subspace Theory
I'm a student delving into functional analysis, and I came across Lemma 2.1.1 "Topics in Banach Spaces" in my studies. It talks about normalized block basic sequences in $l^{p}$, stating that they're isometrically equivalent to the canonical basis. Moreover, it mentions that the range of these sequences corresponds to the image of a contractive projection.
Now, I'm intrigued by the implications of this lemma, particularly regarding the contractive projection. Does this contractive projection always form a proper subspace? Because this lemma is later used to argue the existence of a complemented subspace. For this to work, every contractive projection would need to form a proper subspace. Is this the case, and if so, how would one go about proving it?
I'd appreciate any insights or explanations you could provide on this topic. Thanks in advance for your help!
